# Buck Converter not increasing the current?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, current, dc-dc-converter, buck

I am constructing a 20 W buck converter. The voltage is bucking but the current is not, the current that the power supply is producing is going straight through to the load. Please help.

I am suppose to apply a 12 V input (1.66 A maximum) and get a 5 v output with a maximum of 4 A of current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flePMk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also is it necessary to use the ground terminal (green) of the bench power supply when testing?

Comment: Ah the generic green terminal on the generic power supply feeding a circuit that is driven by the one size fits all generic duty cycle.

Comment: How are you driving your MOSFET? What do you mean by "the current is going straight through to the load"? It sounds like you might be operating this as a linear regulator, dissipating significant power in your FET.

Comment: Should i connect the green ground terminal of the bench power supply to the black negative terminal when testing?

Comment: I am using a TC4428A MOSFET driver which is connected to an ATTINTY85 output. The ATTINY85 is used to generate a PWM at 250 kHz

Comment: There's no particular reason not to ground your circuit, but also no particular reason _to_ ground it, from what we know from your question. So, it doesn't really matter whether you connect ground to negative or not, from what I can see.

Comment: Why is my circuit operating as a linear regulator rather than a buck converter? My current efficiency is around 50% which is terrible for a buck converter. @Felthry

Comment: Naive implementations of switching regulators can sometimes turn into linear regulators if not used correctly, but it sounds like yours isn't with the further information you've given.

Comment: I had posted this question before in more detail on this URL: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/370984/buck-converter-drawing-too-much-current-from-supply but i am still having the issue with the current. I am clueless as to why the current is not increasing @Felthry

Answer (score 3):

TC4428A is a **LOW SIDE** driver, that mosfet is not in a low side configuration, what you need is a high side driver and boost capacitor (You have to get the gate up above the supply rail by 10V or so to switch the mosfet on fully).

As it is your gate can only swing up to the supply rail, which will leave the source Vgs below the supply, thus in the linear region and dissipating considerable power.

You also want some input capacitance and some high frequency output capacitance, a few uF or so of MLCC would probably do.

Comment: +1. Was considering this myself, but didn't know enough to be confident making it an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try using the TC4432 driver as well as a MIC5018.

Comment: MIC5018 is 10V abs max, not a good choice on a 12V rail! The 4432 lacks the oh so useful boost pin, you can probably emulate it, but it will be an annoying fiddle. Something like a UCC27212A would probably be ok, just use the high side half of the part.

Comment: I am unable to get the UCC27212A at my local electronic store, will a IR2112 MOSFET Driver work? @DanMills

Comment: The 2112 is a part really designed for high voltage applications, it has a rather weak peak output current on the high side driver, but if you can live with limited ability to slew a high capacitance gate I see no reason to think it is not workable. You will need an external bootstrap diode and cap of course.

Answer (score 1):

The output current needs to be supplied by the input power supply, in bursts. It's only the average input current that's supposed to be 1.66A, the actual current will cycle between none, and about 4A.

If the input power supply has overcurrent protection, it may shut down on these peaks, messing with your converter. You need an input capacitor across the power supply, which can source these short term current peaks.